# Windows: Where is the Event ID in the EventLog.xml file?

Tags: powershell

Struggling to see where the Event ID is in the EventLog.xml file

The first 10 lines are below

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord</T>
      <T>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventRecord</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord</ToString>
    <Props>
      <I32 N="Id">3</I32>
```

However I can't get the details behind it. Can I actually view the namespace/schema?

Thanks

Comment: From which file this was taken?

Comment: EventLog.xml on a system that was sent to me so haven't more details at the moment

Comment: This doesn't look like an event log at all, more like a credentials XML file.

Comment: This XML file was evidently created using PowerShell (`Export-Clixml`) and contains serialized .NET objects. The lines you show do not contain the event ID. As such, the question cannot be answered with the information given.

Answer (score 0):

#### Where is the Event ID in the EventLog.xml file?

> ```
> <xs:element name="EventID">
>     <xs:complexType>
>         <xs:simpleContent>
>             <xs:extension
>                 base="unsignedInt"
>              />
>         </xs:simpleContent>
>     </xs:complexType>
> </xs:element>
> ```
>
> The EventID element is defined by the [SystemPropertiesType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/eventschema-systempropertiestype-complextype)
>   complex type.

Source [EventID (SystemPropertiesType) Element - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/eventschema-eventid-systempropertiestype-element)

---

#### Can I actually view the namespace/schema?

> The Windows SDK includes the schema in the \Include\Event.xsd file.

Source [Event Schema - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/eventschema-schema)

---

#### Example Extract from System Event log saved as XML

Action > Save All Events As > Save as type: XML

[image]

```
<Events>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General" Guid="{A68CA8B7-004F-D7B6-A698-07E2DE0F1F5D}"/>
      <EventID>1</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000010</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-12-31T13:49:36.485000000Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>265046</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="2180" ThreadID="2196"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Hal</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1699878757-1063190524-3119395976-1001"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NewTime">2019-12-31T13:49:36.485000000Z</Data>
      <Data Name="OldTime">2019-12-31T13:49:36.372437200Z</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Searching the file:

```
F:\test>find "EventID" SystemEvents.xml | more
---------- SYSTEMEVENTS.XML
      <EventID>1</EventID>
      <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
      <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
      <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
      <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
      <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
      <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
      <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
      <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7042</EventID>
      <EventID Qualifiers="32768">6013</EventID>
...
```

Comment: EventID is not in the XML file though

Comment: @pee2pee Yes it is. See modified answer.

Comment: Not if you just have the command line to work with

Comment: @pee2pee ?? You can search the XML file from the command line ...

Comment: As pointed out in a comment on the question your file is **not** an Event Log from Windows.

Comment: It's PowerShell on Linux

Comment: It's the result of saving a Windows event log as XML as opposed to EVTX.